# What variable contains the word "Appendix" when a chapter is an appendix?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, naming

I've designed a whole new fancy chapter header layout, and have hard coded the word "Chapter" in there before the chapter number. I just realized now that this won't work because I have an appendix named "Chapter A".

Is there a variable that will contain the word Chapter or Appendix depending on which it is typesetting at the moment? `\chaptername` only seems to have the word "Chapter" even though I'm using it under the appendix section.

**Edit:** I've got it working in my chapter headers, thanks to answers below; but my TOC isn't working properly. I've changed my TOC with `titletoc`, and it still says "Chapter" even though I've got the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\titlecontents{chapter}[-2em]
    {\color{cyan}\bfseries\LARGE\addvspace{3mm}}
    {\@chapapp \contentslabel{-0.25em}\hspace{2em}}
    {}
    {\hspace{3em}\contentspage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{test}
    \appendix
    \chapter{asdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's called `\@chapapp` so you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the standard classes `book` and `report`, the `\chapter` command uses the internal command `\@chapapp` to typeset chapter headings. `\@chapapp` is initially defined as `\chaptername` ("Chapter"), and redefined to `\appendixname` ("Appendix") as soon as you issue `\appendix` in the document body.

In response to your follow-up question: Here's one (possibly not the most elegant) way to achieve correct naming in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter

\titlecontents{chapter}[-2em]
    {\color{cyan}\bfseries\LARGE\addvspace{3mm}}
    {\@chapapp \contentslabel{-0.25em}\hspace{2em}}
    {}
    {\hspace{3em}\contentspage}

\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*{\protect\@chapapp}{\protect\appendixname}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{test}
    \appendix
    \chapter{asdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@chapapp` indeed works for my custom header. Thanks. But how can I get it to show in my TOC as well? I've modified the TOC with `titletoc` and even though I've surrounded my code with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, it still says "Chapter".

Comment: Do you know how I could redefine `\appendix` to have `\switchchapapp` get fired in that? I'd like to make this work without having to get another user to use esoteric commands.

Comment: @agent154 My bad -- answer improved.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `titlesec`, then the command you look for is `\chaptertitlename` that defaults to `\chaptername`, but it is `\appendixname` in the appendix.